# Trying to apply StickyScroll with Viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, scrollview

In my profile page I have StickyScrollview and viewpager in which I have two fragments each of which attach with recyclerview. Im trying to implement StickySroll and want to achive same like one instagram and whatsapp have but it not working properly as it only scroll view pager content but i want if I scroll then it first header get stick to top and then the viewpager scroll just like instagrama and some other socila media app have.

I used this library 'implementation 'com.github.amarjain07:StickyScrollView:1.0.2'

This is my code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment_home">
    
      <com.amar.library.ui.StickyScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:stickyHeader="@id/linearLayoutCompat9"
        app:stickyFooter="@id/viewpager"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                    android:background="#BAFFFFFF"
                    android:elevation="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:title="My Profile">

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/johnnynew" />


                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center">


                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                        android:id="@+id/Followers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/followers_number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1089"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Followers"
                            android:textColor="#858181"
                            android:textSize="16sp"

                            />


                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

           
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat8">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:tabIconTint="#74FFFFFF"
                    app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#A1000000"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
                    app:tabTextColor="#838383">


                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/firstIt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Post" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:id="@+id/firstItem"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="QnA" />


                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat9"
            tools:ignore="NotSibling" />



  
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


    </com.amar.library.ui.StickyScrollView>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

I tried by changing main layout from linear to contraint even after from constraint to StickyScroll but nothing works.